# Is there representation $A\to End_k(k)$ where $A$ is central simple quaternion algebra over $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Sorry  for my bad English.

Let $k$ be commutative field (if  necessary $k=\mathbb{Q}_p$).

$End_k(k):=\{f:k\to k~|~ f$ is $k$-algebra homomorphism$\}$

> Is there  representation $A\to End_k(k)$ where $A$ is central simple quaternion algebra over $k$?

I'm reading concerned about abelian varieties, and in this book there is little representation for proof, but I don't study about representation theory.

Please tell me.

Comment: What is $End_k(k)$?

Comment: $\ker(A\to k)$ is a two-sided ideal

Comment: $End_k(k)$ is just a copy of $k$. So as reuns says, the kernel of such representation is a two sided ideal, so it is either $A$ or $0$. The first  case cannot happen since $1$ has to be sent to $Id$, the second one cannot happen for dimension reasons.

Comment: @GreginGre The endomorphism algebra of $k$ as a $k$-module is $k$, but OP is talking about endomorphisms of $k$ as a $k$-algebra. There are only two such endomorphisms (trivial and zero). Which means this set of endomorphisms isn't even a $k$-algebra unless $k=\Bbb F_2$.